# Which area measurement to trust? - The same polygon in GoogleEarth v. ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system, google-earth, area

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most accurate coordinate system for calculating areas of polygons?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20054/what-is-the-most-accurate-coordinate-system-for-calculating-areas-of-polygons)

I'm currently involved in comparing the "official metropolitan" areas of several cities against their actual overall urban footprint. The official metro areas' areas can be found in other sources, but I need to get the most recent urban footprint area.

I've found the fastest way to do this is to draw a polygon in Google Earth around a city's urban sprawl. As I want to create an explanatory graphic, I then brought my GE polygon into ArcGIS 10, where I converted it from KMZ to layer, and then saved the layer data as a new feature class in my specific city/map geodatabase.

Now, out of habit, b/c I'm focusing on a specific small area, I'm projecting things in UTM. I checked the attribute of my new "urban footprint" feature class polygon and found there to be an ~600,000m2 difference between the polygon area in Arc and the same polygon's area given in Google Earth.

In light of this, my question is *which area value is more accurate and should I use in future calculations I'm going to do?*

Comment: When computing areas, use--of course!--an equal-area projection.  For more about this, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20054/what-is-the-most-accurate-coordinate-system-for-calculating-areas-of-polygons. In fact, it's really the same question, so to keep this site organized, I will vote to close the current one (which will leave the two linked).

Comment: However, if I'm only calculating the area for a small region (i.e. a single city), it would also be acceptable to project the polygon in that specific UTM zone, no? If I remember correctly, the point of UTM is to minimize all 3 factors to a usable extent within a much reduced region/zone.

Comment: Yes, assuming you don't mind the built-in 0.04% range of error (which in most applications is not a problem). But if you're projecting the polygon specifically to compute its area, and not for any other purpose, why choose UTM? You might as well use an appropriate equal-area projection.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the measurement you're making in GE is adjusted, it will give you an incorrect value. Take a look at this [Esri blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/03/05/measuring-distances-and-areas-when-your-map-uses-the-mercator-projection/) posting about measuring length and area in Web Mercator. The scale distortion for Mercator based on a sphere (which web Mercator is) varies as 1/cos(latitude) ([thanks to Melita Kennedy](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/73363-Measurement-Tool-Error?p=256451&viewfull=1#post256451))

Comment: +1. And note that the *area* distortion is the square of the scale distortion.