# PostGIS: calculate area of intersection of EPSG:27700 polygons?

Tags: postgis

I have two tables in Postgres, both of type `geometry(MultiPolygon,27700)` and I would like to find any that intersect with an area of more than 100 square metres.

I know how to get any that intersect above an arbitrary threshold:

```
SELECT * 
FROM aTable a 
JOIN bTable b
WHERE ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) > 1;
```

However, the area returned here is in (I think) decimal degrees. How can I ensure it is always more than 100 square metres?

Perhaps if I do something like:

```
WHERE ST_Area(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(i.wkb_geometry, w.wkb_geometry), 3857)) > 100
```

that would work, since the unit of EPSG:3857 is metres?

I've read [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111270/area-of-an-epsg-27700-polygon) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20054/coordinate-system-for-accurately-calculating-areas-of-polygons-that-cross-utm-zo/20056#20056) but I don't know what projection to pick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

St_area returns cartesian area for geometries and geodesic areas for geographies.

If your coordinate system is in lat/lan, simply type cast your geometry to geography and your result will be in sq meters

`ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)::geography)`

EDIT:
For projected data, st_area() will always return areas in the linear unit of the projection itself.
EPSG 27700 is the British National Grid projection. It is a Transverse Mercator projection based on the OSGB36 datum. Its linear unit is meter. More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid).

The function

`ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))`

should give you directly an area in sq meters.
If you want to double check, test this

`ST_Area(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom),4326)::geography)`

This transforms your coordinate from BNG to WGS84 and calculates the geodesic area. Results should be somewhat similar to the simple st_area() call above.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I get `ERROR 1: ERROR:  Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography.`. Table a has geometry of type `geometry(Polygon,27700)` and table b has geometry of type `geometry(MultiPolygon,27700)`.

Comment: Maybe I need to transform the intersection before casting it to geography? `ST_Area(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom), 3857)::geography)` -- nope, that gives the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't familiar with the British National Grid and assumed from your question that it was in lat/lon. It is a Transverse Mercator projection and its linear unit is in meters. a simple st_area() call should do. I edited my answer as well.